# Unable to create new Sandbox accounts, i keep getting errors and not found messages

Tags: sandbox, accounts

I have been trying for several days.  When I login to my Paypal developer account I can see some of my sandbox accounts, but when I try and create a new one, it either hangs with the spiny thing there for way too long, up to 20 minutes before I gave up.

I often get file not found when going to the dashboard or Sandbox > Accounts

the something went wrong errors when trying to manually create an account

I have tried so many combinations with suggestions others have used... but nothing works

Tested on two computers, one W10, other W7, using Google Chrome, Firefox and IE/Edge

Any ideas please for a fix or is this a technical issue on Paypal's end?

Thanks